# Visual Studio 2012 Test Controller UI Configuration hangs

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem starting the Test Controller Configuration Tool. There is no error, but it simply hung on the loading state. Event log says: The Controller service could not be started. TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server: [redacted URL]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2013/09/error-tf400324-when-starting-visual.html
Actually QTControllerConfig.xml file was empty so I think that was the problem.